# checkbox not functioning properly in childview of ExpandableListview android

Tags: android, checkbox, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

In my `ExpandableListview`, I am using `Imageview` and `Checkbox` for `childview` that resembles the shape image and name.

When I tick the `checkbox` of particular child item , the other child item also gets ticked, after scrolling the checked state changes.

I needed multiple values to be selected.

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private static final int[] EMPTY_STATE_SET = {};
    private static final int[] GROUP_EXPANDED_STATE_SET =
            {android.R.attr.state_expanded};
    private static final int[][] GROUP_STATE_SETS = {
        EMPTY_STATE_SET, // 0
        GROUP_EXPANDED_STATE_SET // 1
    };
    private Context _context;
    private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
    // child data in format of header title, child title
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

    private ArrayList<Boolean> itemChecked = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
    private boolean[] itemCheckedBoolean =  new boolean[100]; 



    Bitmap bmp;
    LayoutInflater infalInflater;


    ImageLoader imageLoader;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader, HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
        infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();      
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        imageLoader=new ImageLoader(_context);   

        for (int i = 0; i < SearchWhiteDiamondsActivity.shape_list.size(); i++) {
            itemChecked.add(i, false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {

        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);  
        Log.e("_childText", "karjeevch "+childText);


        int itemType = getChildType(groupPosition,childPosition);      


        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        switch (itemType) {

        case 0:
            viewHolder = null;
            if (convertView==null) {

                viewHolder=new ViewHolder();                
                convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_child_shape, null);
                viewHolder.shape_name = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.shape_chk_box);
                //viewHolder.shape_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.shape_chk_box);
                viewHolder.img_shape_icon=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_shape);                


                imageLoader.DisplayImage("http://rosycontact.com/shashvat/images/"+childText.toLowerCase()+".png", viewHolder.img_shape_icon);                
                Log.e("shape", "karjeevshp "+childText);
                viewHolder.shape_name.setText(childText);
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);               

               final CheckBox shape_name_temp=viewHolder.shape_name;
               //final TextView shape_name_temp=viewHolder.shape_name;



               viewHolder.shape_name.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        int id=buttonView.getId();
                        if (id==R.id.shape_chk_box) {

                            if (shape_name_temp.isChecked()==true) {

                                String shape_str=shape_name_temp.getText().toString();
                                All_link.SHAPE_LIST.add(shape_str);
                                Toast.makeText(_context, shape_name_temp.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Log.e("chk_shape", "karjeevch "+shape_name_temp.getText().toString());
                                itemChecked.set(childPosition, true);
                            }
                            else{
                                String shape_str=shape_name_temp.getText().toString();
                                All_link.SHAPE_LIST.remove(shape_str);                              
                                itemChecked.set(childPosition, false);
                            }
                        }                                                                                           
                    }
                });                                                                      
            }
            else{
                //viewHolder=new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
                imageLoader.DisplayImage("http://rosycontact.com/shashvat/images/"+childText.toLowerCase()+".png", viewHolder.img_shape_icon);                                             
                viewHolder.shape_name.setText(childText);                               
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);                             
            }
            return convertView;
```

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: No distractions, no chit-chat (read help→tour), no one who was not going to answer in the first place will answer because your write it is urgent. You are just wasting potential answerers time by having them read through non-essentials.

Comment: No distractions, no chit-chat (read help→tour), no one who was not going to answer in the first place will answer because your write it is urgent. You are just wasting potential answerers time by having them read through non-essentials.

Answer (score 0):

save the state of checkbox ....

```
viewHolder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();  // Here we get the position that we have set for the checkbox using setTag.
                list.get(getPosition).setSelected(buttonView.isChecked()); // Set the value of checkbox to maintain its state.
            }
        });
```